# Add units to geomtext label

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text

I have created a bubble plot and want to give a label to the size of the bubbles. However, I can not see how I can add a unit to the label, i.e. rather than stating "228" to have the label read "228 qq"

The code is:

```
SalesChannells <- read.csv("SalesChannelsData.csv")
View(SalesChannells)
SalesChannelsScatter <- ggplot(SalesChannells, aes(x = SalesChannel, y = NumberOfFarmers, size = TotalVolumeOfCoffee, color = TotalVolumeOfCoffee), alpha=.5) +
  geom_point()
SalesChannelsScatter + 
  scale_size_area(max_size = 30) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  labs(size = "Volume of coffee sold") +
  labs(title="More coffee is sold to intermediaries than to organisations") +
  expand_limits(y=c(0,100)) +
  labs(x="Sales Channel", y="Number of farmers")+
  geom_text(aes(label=TotalVolumeOfCoffee), size=8, color="white",hjust = 1.7)
```

And the plot looks like the following:

[image]

Extra bonus points would be if it was possible to add a nice card behind the label which is a rectangle with one end being triangular, finishing on the centre of the bubble. So far I can only add standard rectangles and not sure how to add a point or position it properly.

Comment: why don't you just replace in your `geom_text` the following `label=paste(TotalVolumeOfCoffee, "qq"))` ?

Comment: That works, many thanks! Ill let you do the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like :

```
geom_text(aes(label=paste(TotalVolumeOfCoffee, "qq")), size=8, color="white", hjust = 1.7)
```

(not tested)

Comment: thanks for copy/pasting my comment into your answer. appreciated

Comment: If it's a sarcasm you'll note you commented while I was typing the answer I hope...